# creating numpy array in c extension segfaults

Tags: python, c, numpy, python-extensions

I'm just trying to start off by creating a numpy array before I even start to write my extension. Here is a super simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Python.h"
#include "numpy/npy_common.h"
#include "numpy/ndarrayobject.h"
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int n = 2;
    int nd = 1;
    npy_intp size = {1};
    PyObject* alpha = PyArray_SimpleNew(nd, &size, NPY_DOUBLE);
    return 0;
}
```

This program segfaults on the `PyArray_SimpleNew` call and I don't understand why. I'm trying to follow some previous questions (e.g. [numpy array C api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924827/numpy-array-c-api) and [C array to PyArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582875/c-array-to-pyarray)). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typical usage of `PyArray_SimpleNew` is for example

```
int nd = 2;
npy_intp dims[] = {3,2};
PyObject *alpha = PyArray_SimpleNew(nd, dims, NPY_DOUBLE);
```

Note that the value of `nd` must not exceed the number of elements of array `dims[]`.

**ALSO:** The extension **[must call](https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/c-api.array.html#importing-the-api)** `import_array()` to set up the C API's function-pointer table:

> This function must be called in the initialization section of a module that will make use of the C-API. It imports the module where the function-pointer table is stored and points the correct variable to it.

E.g. in Cython:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

np.import_array()  # so numpy's C API won't segfault

cdef make_array():
  cdef np.npy_intp element_count = 100
  return np.PyArray_SimpleNew(1, &element_count, np.NPY_DOUBLE)
```

Comment: Right...I was trying to create a 1-D array. Anyways, with your code, I still get a segfault.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. The segfault seems to be related to a required call to `import_array()`. I've never tried calling `PyArray_SimpleNew` from `main` so I'm not sure how to fix this.