# Creating numpy array from c-pointer crashes ipython kernel

Tags: python, numpy, cython

With this code I am trying to create a numpy array from a malloc'ed c pointer, inspired by a [blog post from Gaël Varoquaux](http://gael-varoquaux.info/programming/cython-example-of-exposing-c-computed-arrays-in-python-without-data-copies.html).

The line that creates the array seems to lead to an invalid memory access as it crashes the kernel. What did I do wrong?

```
%%cython -f

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef array_from_pointer(double* ptr, int size):
    cdef np.npy_intp shape_c[1]
    shape_c[0] = <np.npy_intp> size
    ndarray = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, shape_c, np.NPY_FLOAT64, ptr)
    return ndarray


cdef N = 12
cdef double* ptr = <double*> malloc(sizeof(double)*N)

array_from_pointer(ptr, N)
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25496494/2272172

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using numpy's Array API, you need to call `np.import_array()`:

```
%%cython -f

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
np.import_array()

cdef array_from_pointer(double* ptr, int size):
    cdef np.npy_intp shape_c[1]
    shape_c[0] = <np.npy_intp> size
    ndarray = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, shape_c, np.NPY_FLOAT64, ptr)
    return ndarray


cdef N = 12
cdef double* ptr = <double*> malloc(sizeof(double)*N)

array_from_pointer(ptr, N)
```

Failing to do so causes the segmentation fault that crashes the ipython kernel.