# Segmentation fault creating PyArrayObject using PyArray_SimpleNew

Tags: c, numpy, c-api

I am creating a C extension for NumPy. The function should return an array, so I decided to create a `PyArrayObject` with dimensions 50x10 using `PyArray_SimpleNew` and later fill it with some values. Here is the code:

```
PyArrayObject *a; npy_intp dims[2];
dims[0] = 50; dims[1] = 10;
a = (PyArrayObject *) PyArray_SimpleNew(2, dims, NPY_DOUBLE);
```

However, the creation of the array a in the third line produces Segmentation Fault. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: maybe [creating numpy array in c extension segfaults](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25496494/2055064) helps, did you call `import_array()` ?

Comment: Oh, thank you. I just posted a solution because I did not check your comment before. Anyway, it indeed fix the problem. Now the question is why?

Comment: "void import_array(void):
This function must be called in the initialization section of a module that will make use of the C-API. It imports the module where the function-pointer table is stored and points the correct variable to it."  textually copied from NumPy C-API doc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [creating numpy array in c extension segfaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494858/creating-numpy-array-in-c-extension-segfaults)

Answer (score 4):

I needed to include `import_array()` in my init function as shown below. I don't know what `import_array()` does, but fix the problem.

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_multpy(void)
{
    import_array();
    return PyModule_Create(&multpymodule);
}
```

PS: It would be wonderful to know why `import_array()` has to be called in the `PyMODINIT_FUNC`. If somebody knows, please explain.