# Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE9ECECF19 in ...: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x000000F632EFEC68

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I have compiled `Matplot++ 1.2.0` into a static `lib` file using the following commands:

```
1. git clone https://github.com/alandefreitas/matplotplusplus.git

2. cd matplotplusplus

3. mkdir build

4. cd build

5. cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..

6. cmake --build . --config Debug
```

Then I created a Windows Console application project. Then I added the iclude path, lib path, and lib file-names from the project settings for both the debug and release settings separately.

Then I changed the code generation to `ISO C++17`.

Then I built the project with the following message:

```
#include <matplot\matplot.h>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    try {
        using namespace matplot;

        // Generate some data to plot
        std::vector<double> x = linspace(0, 2 * pi, 100);
        std::vector<double> y = transform(x, [](double xi) { return sin(xi); });

        // Plot the data
        plot(x, y);

        // Display the plot with appropriate labels
        title("Sine Wave");
        xlabel("x");
        ylabel("sin(x)");

        // Save the plot to a file
        save("sine_wave.png");

        // Show the plot in a window
        show();
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
        std::cerr << "Runtime error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MatplotPlusPlus__test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>   Creating library C:\git\MatPlotPlusPlus__test\x64\Debug\MatplotPlusPlus__test.lib and object C:\git\MatPlotPlusPlus__test\x64\Debug\MatplotPlusPlus__test.exp
1>MatplotPlusPlus__test.vcxproj -> C:\git\MatPlotPlusPlus__test\x64\Debug\MatplotPlusPlus__test.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

However, when I execute the project, I get the following error without exception handling:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE9ECECF19 in MatplotPlusPlus__test.exe: 
Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x000000F632EFEC68.
```

I get the followinh error with exception handling:

```
Runtime error: popen() failed!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

[image]

This error is pointing to the file `C:\git\MatPlotPlusPlus__test\external_libs\Matplot++ 1.2.0\include\matplot\freestanding\plot.h`.

**What is causing this issue?**

Comment: Related/dupe: [Matplotlib-cpp plot works in debug but fails in release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74024667/matplotlib-cpp-plot-works-in-debug-but-fails-in-release)

Comment: @user12002570, Matplot++ and MalplotLibCPP are two different libraries.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the call stack?

Comment: *How can I resolve this issue?* Step through the code in the debugger. Set breakpoints to narrow down where the issue is happening, and then set breakpoints in that area of the code and single step through to see what's happening. Expecting us to debug code we cannot see isn't how things work here.

Comment: @273K, Yes, I checked the call stack. The exception is being generated on the first statement related to `Matplot++` which is `plot(x, y);`

Comment: @KenWhite, I am not expecting anyone to debug the code.

Comment: @273K, Does Matplot++ depend on Python? I thought, no.

Comment: The master branch may be unstable. Why not use `vcpkg install matplotplusplus` as for the manual?

Comment: @273K, Never used that command before on Windows.

Comment: `popen() failed!` makes me wonder what it is trying to run and where it expects to find it. If it is supposed to be relative to the working directory of the program and you're running in the debugger then you'll probably need to set that in the debugging options. Properties->Debugging->Working Directory.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, I try to set the working directory to `$(ProjectDir)` and `$(SolutionDir)x64\Debug`. Neither of them worked.

Comment: Based on the exception and looking at the code it looks like it may be trying to run `gnuplot`. Is that in the working directory or in your path?

Comment: @RetiredNinja, *... trying to run gnuplot. Is that in the working directory or in your path?* --- No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [image]

Indeed, the Matplot++ calls GNUplot to render the graphics.

So, I installed GNUPlot, and now my program is displaying the plot.

[image]